# Dynamic Menustrip access vb.net

Tags: vb.net, controls, menustrip

I'm adding MenuStrips dynamically based on number of rs232 ports available.
The thing is i want to access the controls text in order to use them in the connection.

```
Private Sub FormConnection_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    myPort = IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames()

    Dim Ports As Array = CType(myPort, Object())
    If Ports.Length = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("No connections available.")
    Else

        Dim PortsLength As Integer = Ports.Length
        For Length As Integer = 0 To PortsLength - 1

            Dim Item As New ToolStripMenuItem(Ports(Length).ToString, Nothing, _
            New EventHandler(AddressOf MenuCOMclick))
            Item.CheckOnClick = True
            Item.Name = "COMDYN" + Length.ToString
            PortsToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(Item)
        Next
End If
```

Now i want to add a Event **MenuCOMclick** where one of the menus is clicked, all the others are unchecked.

I tried to create an array of controls but the menustrips don't work like that..
How can i do that then ?

```
Private Sub MenuCOMclick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
   ???
   ???
   ???
End Sub
```

Thank you

Comment: what do you mean by "all the others are unchecked" ?

Comment: not "are unchecked", sorry . I want to uncheck them all except the one i'm clicking.. And how to access them in order to know which one is checked, to use later in my program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thats the way to access ToolStripMenuItems in your `MenuStrip`,
note that if you want to access the `sender` (the control that was raised the event) you need to cast the sender to the control type.

also you can itterate all ToolStripMenuItems. read my comments, hope it helps.

```
Private Sub MenuCOMclick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' thats how you can check the name of the sender
    MsgBox(CType(sender, ToolStripMenuItem).Name)
    ' thats how you can itterate all ToolStripMenuItem 
    For Each itm As ToolStripMenuItem In MenuStrip1.Items
        For Each Childitm As ToolStripMenuItem In itm.DropDownItems
            MsgBox(Childitm.Name) ' show name of the item
            ' example to access all items properties accept the sender
            If Childitm.Name <> CType(sender, ToolStripMenuItem).Name Then
                itm.ForeColor = Color.Beige
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```